# Macro to Copy Header Formatting

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel file that has 8 region's training information and I have a macro setup that will compile all 8 sheets into a master sheet that I can use to Pivot.

Everything works fine except I can't get it to properly format the master sheet properly.

The code for the copying of the headers:

```
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(DestSh.UsedRange) = 0 Then
      sh.Range("A1:Z1").Copy DestSh.Range("A1")
    End If
```

I need wrapping of text on all columns and to have a filter on them.

Entire code:

```
Select Code  copy to clipboard
Sub CopyDataWithHeaders()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim DestSh As Worksheet
    Dim Last As Long
    Dim shLast As Long
    Dim CopyRng As Range
    Dim StartRow As Long

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    'Delete the sheet "Master Sheet" if it exist
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Master Sheet").Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    'Add a worksheet with the name "Master Sheet"
    Set DestSh = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    DestSh.Name = "Master Sheet"

    'Fill in the start row
    StartRow = 2

    'loop through all worksheets and copy the data to the DestSh
    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If sh.Name <> DestSh.Name Then

    'Copy header row, change the range if you use more columns
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(DestSh.UsedRange) = 0 Then
      sh.Range("A1:Z1").Copy DestSh.Range("A1")
    End If

            'Find the last row with data on the DestSh and sh
            Last = LastRow(DestSh)
            shLast = LastRow(sh)

            'If sh is not empty and if the last row >= StartRow copy the CopyRng
            If shLast > 0 And shLast >= StartRow Then

                'Set the range that you want to copy
                Set CopyRng = sh.Range(sh.Rows(StartRow), sh.Rows(shLast))

                'Test if there enough rows in the DestSh to copy all the data
                If Last + CopyRng.Rows.Count > DestSh.Rows.Count Then
                    MsgBox "There are not enough rows in the Destsh"
                    GoTo ExitTheSub
                End If

                'This example copies values/formats, if you only want to copy the
                'values or want to copy everything look below example 1 on this page
                CopyRng.Copy
                With DestSh.Cells(Last + 1, "A")
                    .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                    .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
                    Application.CutCopyMode = False
                End With

            End If

        End If
    Next

ExitTheSub:

    Application.Goto DestSh.Cells(1)

    'AutoFit the column width in the DestSh sheet
    DestSh.Columns.AutoFit

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
End Sub

Function LastRow(sh As Worksheet)
    On Error Resume Next
    LastRow = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                            After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                            Lookat:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Row
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Any ideas on what I need to add to this code?

Comment: It's not clear why the code to copy the headers is in the loop.  Are they the same on all 8 worksheets?

Comment: Yes, they're the exact same on all worksheets. All the other worksheets use the same headers but they just have different training information and it feeds up to the master sheet. I'm trying to test out this macro and I'm running into some issues with spacing as well so I guess I'll have to do some thorough testing before piloting it.

Answer (score 2):

If all the headers are the same, just copy them on your first trip through the loop:

```
StartRow = 1

For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If sh.Name <> DestSh.Name Then
        Last = LastRow(DestSh)
        shLast = LastRow(sh)
        If shLast > 0 And shLast >= StartRow Then
            Set CopyRng = sh.Range(sh.Rows(StartRow), sh.Rows(shLast))
            If Last + CopyRng.Rows.Count > DestSh.Rows.Count Then
                MsgBox "There are not enough rows in the Destsh"
                GoTo ExitTheSub
            End If

            CopyRng.Copy
            With DestSh.Cells(Last + 1, "A")
                .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
            End With
            If StartRow = 1 Then StartRow = 2
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Comment: It was already copying over the contents of the headers but it wouldn't carry over the proper formatting wrapping text or filters on the headers. Do you think it has something to do with the fact that my code deletes the "Master Sheet" and recreates it every time the code is ran? I'm not sure how to adjust it to just update the "Master Sheet' starting from A2. Also the code is putting like 5 spaces between each sheet's data.